# How to use Axis2c to generate C files from WSDL file

Tags: c, web-services, wsdl, axis2c, wsdl2code

I want to use a webservice in C code. I am trying to make a client. I need something to do what Axis2java does and generates the classes from a wsdl files. 
I found that Axis2c makes (.c) files generated from wsdl file.
I downloaded it from [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/download.cgi) . unzipped it. I created the environment variable for AXIS2C_HOME and I created AXIS2C_CLASSPATH.
but I can't make it work.

when I type this command :

```
WSDL2C -uri -ss -sd -d none -u -f -o
```

I get this error :

```
echo off
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2C
```

how can I solve this problem. and please tell me how to use this Axis2c tool properly.

Thank you in advance.

@loentar :  I installed Axis2/Java and I set the environment variable for it. now I run the wsdl2c.bat I get this :

```
E:\dev\Tools\axis2c-bin-1.6.0-win32\bin\tools\wsdl2c>WSDL2C.bat

E:\dev\Tools\axis2c-bin-1.6.0-win32\bin\tools\wsdl2c>echo off
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp 
    -classpath 
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D=
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:...|:]
    -enableassertions[:...|:]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:...|:]
    -disableassertions[:...|:]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:[=]
                  load native agent library , e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:[=]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:[=]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
```

after that I run this command :

```
E:\dev\Tools\axis2c-bin-1.6.0-win32\bin\tools\wsdl2c>WSDL2C.bat -uri hello.wsdl
-u -uw

E:\dev\Tools\axis2c-bin-1.6.0-win32\bin\tools\wsdl2c>echo off
Unrecognized option: -uri
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

what can I do ?
I'm using windows 8 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the envinroment variable for JAVA_HOME, AXIS2_HOME, AXIS2C_HOME, and added their lib folder to CLASSPATH. after running this command:
 WSDL2C.bat -uri hello.wsdl -u -uw 
I got this message:

```
echo off 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2C
```

I found the solution myself. :)
I double checked if I had created the environment variable for AXIS2_HOME and I saw that it is there, correctly.
in spite of it's existence I tried to set it again in command prompt. so I typed:

```
SET AXIS2_HOME=E:\dev\Tools\axis2-1.6.2
```

then I typed the command for WSDL2C code generator:

```
WSDL2C.bat -uri hello.wsdl -u -uw
```

And BAM ! it worked properly.
Now I can generate C files from WSDL file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Axis2/C you must have Axis2/Java installed.

`AXIS2_HOME` must point to Axis2/Java installation.

For details please see [README](https://axis2c-unofficial.googlecode.com/hg/tools/codegen/javatool/README) of codegen.

The complete list of commands to create and compile client is:

```
# create stubs
sh $AXIS2C_HOME/bin/tools/wsdl2c/WSDL2C.sh -uri Calculator.wsdl -u -uw

# implement main() in src/your_client.c
# see samples/codegen/client/calculator for example

# compile and link client
gcc -o calculator_client src/*.c -I$AXIS2C_HOME/include/axis2-1.6.0 -L$AXIS2C_HOME/lib -laxutil -laxis2_axiom -laxis2_parser -laxis2_engine -lpthread -laxis2_http_sender -laxis2_http_receiver -ldl -Wl,--rpath -Wl,$AXIS2C_HOME/lib
```

Comment: I still can't make it work. I explained in the question above.